# Click right mouse button to snap window being dragged to screen quarter

Tags: autohotkey

I'm close, but I can't get my trigger to work. I would like to be able to snap the window I'm currently dragging (active) to a quarter of the screen by right clicking while I dragging. It should snap to the quarter of the screen that my mouse is currently over. The trigger is what I feel I'm missing: when I release the right mouse button, winmove the active window to the dimensions relative to where the mouse is. Advice?

```
~Lbutton & ~Rbutton::

    CoordMode,Mouse,Screen  ;mouse position relative to the screen
    MouseGetPos,Xpos,Ypos   ;get mouse position coordinates
    ;WinGet, active_id, ID, A
    ;msgbox %Xpos%,%Ypos%   ;show the saved mouse coordinates 

    RIGHT_height=537
    RIGHT_width=848
    RIGHT_leftpos=1680
    RIGHT_rightpos=2523
    RIGHT_toppos=-70
    RIGHT_vp=460    

    LEFT_height=518
    LEFT_width=847
    LEFT_leftpos=-8
    LEFT_rightpos=834
    LEFT_toppos=-10
    LEFT_vp=503

    ;LEFT SCREEN
    if (Xpos < LEFT_rightpos and ypos < LEFT_vp) {  ;LEFT top left
        WinMove,Untitled - Notepad,,%LEFT_leftpos%,%LEFT_toppos%,%LEFT_width%,%LEFT_height%

    }

    if (Xpos > LEFT_rightpos and Xpos < 1680 and ypos < LEFT_vp) {  ;LEFT top right
        MsgBox LEFT top right
    }

    if (Xpos < LEFT_rightpos and Xpos < 1680 and ypos > LEFT_vp) {  ;LEFT top right
    msgbox LEFT Bottom Left
    }

    if (Xpos > LEFT_rightpos and Xpos < 1680 and ypos > LEFT_vp) {  ;LEFT top right
    msgbox LEFT Bottom Right
    }

    ;RIGHT SCREEN
    if (Xpos < RIGHT_rightpos and Xpos >= 1680 and ypos < RIGHT_vp) {   ;RIGHT top left
    msgbox RIGHT Top Left
    }

    if (Xpos > RIGHT_rightpos and Xpos >= 1680 and ypos < RIGHT_vp) {   ;RIGHT top right
    msgbox RIGHT Top Right
    }

    if (Xpos < RIGHT_rightpos and Xpos >= 1680 and ypos > RIGHT_vp) {   ;RIGHT top right
    msgbox RIGHT Bottom Left
    }

    if (Xpos > RIGHT_rightpos and Xpos >= 1680 and ypos > RIGHT_vp) {   ;RIGHT top right
    msgbox RIGHT Bottom Right
    }


return
```

Comment: I didn't quite catch your problem, could you please elaborate on that? How does it behave at the moment and how do you want it to behave?

Comment: It looks like you've asked this question before, and it has an answer. [Link here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644176/snapping-windows-4-to-a-screen-with-the-mouse-one-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this maybe

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
hx := A_ScreenWidth/2, hy := A_ScreenHeight/2
return

#if GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
RButton up::
Send {LButton up}
WinGet, aWin, ID, A

MouseGetPos, oX, oY, oWin, oControl
if (oX<hx) and (oY<hy)
    WinMove, AHk_id %aWin%,, 0,0, %hx%, %hy%
else if (oX>hx) and (oY>hy)
    WinMove, AHk_id %aWin%,, %hx%,%hy%, %hx%, %hy%
else if (oX>hx) and (oY<hy)
    WinMove, AHk_id %aWin%,, %hx%,0, %hx%, %hy%
else if (oX<hx) and (oY>hy)
    WinMove, AHk_id %aWin%,, 0,%hy%, %hx%, %hy%
return
```

may work for you but only on a one screen setup

Comment: MCL, you are correct, it was answered on a different post. Sorry for the duplicate postings; it took me a while to figure out this site.